# Применение функции XMLTABLE к XML содержащего кириллическое имя пространства имен

Tags: xml, db2, xquery

В базе данных хранится XML-файл содержащий русскоязычные имена простанств имен

```
<ТегА xmlns="http://фр.рф/А/Б" xmlns:БББ="http://фр.рф/А/Б/варианты" xmlns:ВВВ="http://фр.рф/В">
 <ТегБ>
  <БББ:ТегВ>содержимое</БББ:ТегВ>
 </ТегБ>
 <СлужебнаяИнформация>
  <ВВВ:GUID>ab959b10-3ce0-4e02-8a5b-e9eec399f3c5</ВВВ:GUID>
  <ВВВ:ДатаВремя>2016-05-07T14:45:11+03:00</ВВВ:ДатаВремя>
 </СлужебнаяИнформация>
</ТегА>
```

Запрос вида:

```
SELECT X.*
FROM ShemaName.Tablename T, 
   XMLTABLE(
       'declare default element namespace "http://фр.рф/А/Б";
       declare namespace U="http://фр.рф/А/Б/варианты";
       $d' PASSING T.XMLField AS "d"
   COLUMNS 
      T VARCHAR(1000) PATH 'ТегА/ТегБ/U:ТегВ'
   ) AS X
```

Приводит к ошибке:

```
ERROR [10504] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL16032N
The string "http://фр.рф/А/Б" is not a valid URI. Error QName=err:XQST0046.
```

Если в запросе не объявлять пространства имен и использовать конструкцию PATH вида

```
'*:ТегА/*:ТегБ/*:ТегВ'
```

то запрос работает, но по определенным причинам это меня не устраивает (реальный XML сложнее и пространства имен там не просто так).

Есть ли способ обойти это ограничение на именование пространств имен?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно закодировать домен в punycode, а строку запроса в UTF, используя percent‐encoding

Например, вместо `http://фр.рф/А/Б` писать `http://xn--p1ah.xn--p1ai/%D0%90/%D0%91`

Comment: Можно. И так запрос даже выполнится без ошибки, только вот не вернет ничего поскольку URI атрибута xmlns обрабатывается XML парсером как простая строка. Чтобы такой вариант работал надо чтобы и в XML имена пространств в punycode были.